# Battery drainage and Suspension/Hibernation issue

Tags: windows-10, battery, sleep, lenovo-laptop, hibernate

After some time searching for a solution and arriving at none, I come to your help.

I possess a Lenovo Thinkpad T14, and it's been giving me some problems for which I cannot identify the source.

Problems:

1. While putting the PC to sleep/hibernation, sometimes the screen lights up by itself without any prompt;
2. While on hibernation/sleep mode, I can still hear the fans working, sometimes as loud as if the computer was awake;
3. Related to the previous problem (I think): while on sleep mode, the battery seems to drain as if it were being used.

I own another Lenovo Thinkpad T490s, which does not give me any of these problems, which makes me think it may be a 'model related' problem.

I've tried to check `powercfg -waketimer`, which yielded

```
Timer set by [PROCESS] \Device\HarddiskVolume2\Windows\SystemApps\Microsoft.Windows.StartMenuExperienceHost_cw5n1h2txyewy\StartMenuExperienceHost.exe expires at 04:00:00
```

Answer (score 1):

There will be an indicator on the outside of the case when in sleep mode. It may be the red dot over the "i" in ThinkPad.

Make certain when you close the lid that the red light blinks.

I know from experience that incorrect power management setup that "sleep" can be turned off meaning the laptop stays on when the lid is closed.

Now with Lenovo Vantage or System Update (either one) update ALL drivers including for sure BIOS, Chipset and Power Drivers.

Restart after all this.

Then,Control Panel, Power Options:

Check and set the settings for:

"Choose what the power buttons do"

"Choose what closing the lid does"

Then select the Balanced Plan, Change Plan Settings.

Make sure Display and Sleep are both properly set for Battery and Plugged in.

Review completely all the settings I mentioned.  Restart.  Check the Sleep functions.

Properly set, and assuming no hardware problems, all ThinkPads will sleep properly.

It may be worth your while to disable Hibernation while making these changes. I find Sleep adequate and Hibernation not really necessary.

Comment: Thank you very much and sorry for the delay. I tried everything you said. However, the problem still remains!

Comment: You may wish to contact Lenovo Support at this point.